# How to make a launcher(.desktop) file that will open the desired file in a specific app?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, virtualbox, .desktop

I basically want to make a launcher for my Windows 7 vbox file.

I tried the normal way of giving the path to the *Windows 7.vbox* file in the .desktop file but that did not work! maybe as it is not executable.

But when i manually navigate to it from nautilus and click on it,the VM straight away starts windows 7.

How do I achieve this in the shortcut?

I also thought of first changing to the directory and then executing it but when i tried it in the command line it dint work.

just `Windows\ 7.vbox` gave me command not found and
   `./Windows\ 7.vbox` gave me permission denied and with sudo it gave command not found again.

I am using ORACLE VIRTUAL BOX 4.1.12

Comment: You do not run the Windows 7 vbox file directly, you need to run the Oravcle Virtual Box application, and send it the Windows 7 file as a parameter. This what Nautilus actually does for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the `Exec` field of your .desktop file, you have to place:

```
Exec=xdg-open "/home/Nirmik/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/Windows 7.vbox"
```

`xdg-open` will load the vbox file with the default program, VirtualBox!

Edit the above path so as to match your needs, of course.

Comment: so basically the command `xdg-open` opens the file in the default app?

Comment: yes yeah yes yeah

Comment: It dint work! here is the .desktop file- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1155785/

Comment: Please read carefully my answer. Notice that I have removed the \ before the spaces inside the path. The \ are required only if you haven't enclosed the path with ", but you've already done so. Also, you have 2 `Name` fields?

Comment: umm yeah thats how i always make a .desktop file with 2 name fields...and i'll correct on that \ thing

Comment: okhay!! that worked! thanx! :)